# Get the closest datetime from a list

Tags: python, datetime

in Python, if I have a `datetime` and a list of `datetime`s, e.g.:

```
import datetime as dt
date = dt.datetime(1970, 1,1)

dates = [dt.datetime(1970, 1, 2), dt.datetime(1970, 1,3)]
```

How I can get the `datetime` in the list that's closest to `date`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) with a custom `key` parameter:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> date = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
>>> dates = [dt.datetime(1970, 1, 2), dt.datetime(1970, 1, 3)]
>>> min(dates, key=lambda d: abs(d - date))
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 2, 0, 0)
```

Subtracting two [`datetime` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) gives a [`timedelta` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
>>> map(lambda d: abs(d - date), dates)
[datetime.timedelta(1), datetime.timedelta(2)]
```

which behaves as you'd expect in comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

If they are in order you could also use bisect:

```
import datetime as dt
date = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1,12)

dates = [dt.datetime(1970, 1, 2), dt.datetime(1970, 1,3)]

from bisect import bisect

ind = bisect(dates, date, hi=len(dates)-1)

print(min(dates[ind], dates[ind-1],key=lambda x: abs(x - date)))
```

Finding the upper bound is `O(log n)` and then we just compare the upper with the lower element which is  `dates[ind-1]`, so for a sorted list it is `O(log n)` vs `O(n)`.

Comment: This only gives the insertion position, not the date that is closest. Bisection is great to reduce the number of comparisons made by `min()` but you are not quite there yet. What if the input is `[dt.datetime(1970, 1, 2), dt.datetime(1970, 1, 13)]` for example; your solution returns `dt.datetime(1971, 1, 2)` while the other date is clearly a lot closer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it behaves exactly the same as the min example on a list of sorted datetimes, what is missing?  `print(min(dates, key=lambda d: abs(d -date)))` also returns `dt.datetime(1970, 1, 2)`

Comment: Ah, no, I misread the date there. I thought it was 1970-01-12, not 1970-01-01 12:00 noon.

Comment: But if the date *were* 1970-01-12 then your code produces a different result from jon's.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it actually produces the same as Jon's  but there is a bug I am trying to figure out.

Comment: I produced the wrong edgecase for you; if the date is greater than a and lower than b, it'll always return b regardless of closeness to either. So for `[dt.datetime(1969, 12, 31), dt.datetime(1970, 1, 12)]` as list, and the date searched set to 1970-01-01, you return 1970-01-12.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. that is the bug ;) I am trying to find a nice way to handle that

Comment: You handle it by using `bisect()` to get the upper limit. The lower limit is the index to the left, and you then can find the closest one. This is a refinement of jon's approach, you limit the number of elements to compare against to just those 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I had something similar done, I was trying to find a way to do it with just bisect but obviously not possible. Thanks. I see you are winning the election by a landslide ;)

Comment: Now add an explanation as to why this is better. :-P (hint: O(N) vs O(logN))

Comment: e.g. on a list of 1000 dates, do you want to do 1000 comparisons, or just 10?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, if the dates were hot women yes, if the dates are dates then no ;)